# Radius of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

After finding the radius of convergence using:

$R=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$ or $R=\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}$

What is the requirement from the end points so we can decided if the convergence is on a closed or open interval?

Comment: Have you heard of the terms, "Conditionally convergent" and "Absolutely convergent"?

Comment: @KingDuken yes if it converges with absolute value or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple test for that. You'll need to plug the found radius into the power series and investigate the convergence there as special cases.